# When to use property-ref attribute in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have done the sample program. I used property-ref attribute. Even if I do not use also it is still working. Please let me know what is the actual usage of property-ref attribute in this program.

```
 <hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.onetone">
 <class name="Book" table="BOOK">
    <id name="id" column="BOOK_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="title" type="string" column="TITLE" />
    <property name="description" type="string" column="DESCRIPTION" />
    <property name="publishedDate" type="date" column="PUBLISHED" />

    <many-to-one name="author" class="com.hibernate.onetone.Author"
        column="author_id" unique="true" not-null="true"
        cascade="all" />             
   </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>

  <hibernate-mapping package="com.hibernate.onetone">
  <class name="Author" table="AUTHOR">
    <id name="id" column="AUTHOR_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="NAME" />
    <property name="email" column="EMAIL" />  

   <!--  <property name="serialNumber" column="SerialNumber" /> -->
    <one-to-one name="book" class="Book" property-ref="author"
   constrained="true" cascade="all"/>    
   </class> 
  </hibernate-mapping>

   public class Book {
   private long id;
   private String title;
   private String description;
   private Date publishedDate;
   private Author author;       
   }
  public class Author {
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private Book book;     {
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

property-ref attribute is used to make an  association bi-directional and specify which side of the association is the owner of the relationship.
In the generated query it would result in an update on the foreign key only when the owner of the relationship is updated not the other side.

As in the docs

> property-ref (optional): the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.

Please also look at the below link for more information

http://www.allappforum.com/hibernate/hibernate_o_r_mapping_one_to_one_element.htm

http://www.allappforum.com/hibernate/hibernate_o_r_mapping_many_to_one_element.htm

It would be great if you could also provide you mapping and execution code so that i can make the explanation more clear:)

Comment: As i said earlier property-ref is used to mark the owner of the  relationship.

Comment: Where in the documentation did you see "bi-directional" being used regarding property-ref?

Answer (score 1):

property-ref is used to mark the owner of the  relationship.

Here you have created a bidirectional association between Book and Author . It means that when you have an Book instance you could user the getAuthor() to retrieve the Author instance of that book . Similarly you also have a Book instance in the Author class so that you can navigate back to the Book instance .

In the Book entity mapping you specify the foreign key to the Author as below

```
<many-to-one name="author" class="com.hibernate.onetone.Author"
    column="author_id" unique="true" not-null="true"
    cascade="all" />
```

But from the Author class you need to specify the foreign key on the other side of the relationship that should be joined with the primary key of the Author.How can you do that ?? You use property-ref attribute.

Now if you will not use property-ref attribute in your one-to-one mapping Hibernate will try to join the primary key of the Author class with the primary key of the Book class in order to resolve the association.

Below is the query generated by hibernate to fetch an Author by its identifier using get()

With property-ref

```
select
    author0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I1_0_0_,
    author0_.NAME as NAME2_0_0_,
    author0_.EMAIL as EMAIL3_0_0_,
    book1_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_1_,
    book1_.TITLE as TITLE2_1_1_,
    book1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_1_1_,
    book1_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE4_1_1_,
    book1_.author_id as author_i5_1_1_ 
from
    AUTHOR author0_ 
left outer join
    BOOK book1_ 
        on author0_.AUTHOR_ID=book1_.author_id 
where
    author0_.AUTHOR_ID=?
```

Without property-ref

```
select
    author0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I1_0_0_,
    author0_.NAME as NAME2_0_0_,
    author0_.EMAIL as EMAIL3_0_0_,
    book1_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_1_,
    book1_.TITLE as TITLE2_1_1_,
    book1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_1_1_,
    book1_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE4_1_1_,
    book1_.author_id as author_i5_1_1_ 
from
    AUTHOR author0_ 
left outer join
    BOOK book1_ 
        on author0_.AUTHOR_ID=book1_.BOOK_ID 
where
    author0_.AUTHOR_ID=?
```

Notice the difference in the join condition

With property ref the join in on author_id of book and author_id of Author as below

on author0_.AUTHOR_ID=book1_.author_id

without property ref the join is on author_id of author and book_id of book as below

on author0_.AUTHOR_ID=book1_.BOOK_ID

This is in line with what the docs says as below

> property-ref (optional): the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.

So when you provide property ref it joins with the foreign key of Book as specified in the property ref

```
  <one-to-one name="book" class="Book" property-ref="author" cascade="all"/>
```

and when you have not provided the property ref it joins with the primary key of Book

```
  <one-to-one name="book" class="Book" cascade="all"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**property-ref** (optional): the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.

The property-ref attribute should only be used for mapping legacy data where a foreign key refers to a unique key of the associated table other than the primary key. This is a complicated and confusing relational model. For example, if the Product class had a unique serial number that is not the primary key. The unique attribute controls Hibernate's DDL generation with the SchemaExport tool.

```
<property name="serialNumber" unique="true" type="string" column="SERIAL_NUMBER"/>
```

Then the mapping for OrderItem might use:

```
<many-to-one name="product" property-ref="serialNumber" column="PRODUCT_SERIAL_NUMBER"/>
```

This is not encouraged, however.

If the referenced unique key comprises multiple properties of the associated entity, you should map the referenced properties inside a named  element.

If the referenced unique key is the property of a component, you can specify a property path:

```
<many-to-one name="owner" property-ref="identity.ssn" column="OWNER_SSN"/>
```

for more information : [mapping-declaration-properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-properties)

Comment: So then why is it that 

1. The property must exist on server startup or else fatal error occurs 
2. I fix it to reference an actually existing property name in `property-ref=` 
3. Application now starts up successfully but gives me "Failed to resolve property: myPropertyInsidePropertyRef" on SELECT
4. I remove the property-ref entirely and it works
5. why do #3 and #4 both display the SAME HQL being run according to the logs, but one works and the other throws a HibernateException error, when I clearly fixed the property name in #3 since my application can now start successfully?